# Schema Design : Advice Needed

Tags: database, design, database-design, architecture

I have a distributed data collection system where I have first layer as regional Databases where all collected data is initially stored and master database where all the data is consolidated, what are you thoughts on schema design of this situation, also important thing here is I could have overlapping Ids and dictionary tables are shared by all regional db and also in future there could be need to add new regional Dbs.

I am not sure how to start on designing the schema for this situation and would like to discuss with SO Community ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the natural keys are hard to identify, you can still use surrogates for both regional databases and the master one.

For example, regional database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  region_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  region_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  [other fields],
  PRIMARY KEY (region_id)
);
```

The master database schema would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  region_id INT NOT NULL,
  region_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  [other fields],
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The trick is to have every regional system to supply unique value for "region_name" field. Then each system will happily collect data and no problems will happen during aggregation. The master database will have its own unique IDs and there is going to be a reference to the origin of data (region_id, region_name).

The biggest headache with this approach is references to other tables. When you copy data from regional to master database, you will also have to employ similar approach to other tables, which is, as I said, a headache.

Another way is to use a compound PK:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  region_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  region_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  [other fields],
  PRIMARY KEY (region_id, region_name)
);
```

This way the table is going to look exactly the same between regions and the master. At the same time, compound keys is a headache on its own.

As I'm writing this answer, I understand that there is no easy solution, as always :)

**Update:**

If a natural key is used then there is going to be one unified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  id CAHR(32) NOT NULL, -- most likely ID is going to be a string, not number
  region_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- if you want to keep the info about the origin of data
  [other fields],
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The idea of a natural key, that it's unique regardless of a region. In books, the usual examples are Social Security Number, Passport Number, etc.

You can have a simple hybrid solution. The schema stays as depicted above, and you calculate ID values yourself:

```
UYT49.2873645
UYT49.2873646
UYT23.7824
```

The first part of the string is your region id, the second part - auto-incremental number. As a whole, the string is globally unique which is what you want.

Comment: Let say if I want to make use of Natural key then how would solution change ?

Comment: @rachel I updated the answer

Comment: @Yuriy - You say the natural primary key is probably a string but that does not have to be the case; a composite key can also be natural.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a GUID as your primary key for each entry in the database.  When your regional databases are merged, you wont have to worry about duplicated id's.

Answer (score 2):

Try to identify natural keys from your data, they will not cause the same problems as surrogates when you come to merge your data.

Comment: Tony, can you elaborate more on your suggestion so that I can understand from Design perspective, right now I am not able to get much out of your suggestion.

Comment: Apologies for not elaborating, I posted my quick answer then was off-line for a while but it seems Yuriy's answer has provided you with what you need to know.

Comment: Tony, if you elaborate and I get better understanding than it would be very helpful. I will wait to see your updates.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, use any UUID implementation, GUID being one of them.  It practically guarantees that the ids you generate are unqiue. More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

The benefit of using it among others is - most of the programming languages/ technologies/frameworks/databases supports it, as it is an industry standard (RFC Link : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt ). Excerpts from RFC ...

> 1. Motivation
>
>    One of the main reasons for using
>      UUIDs is that no centralized
>      authority is required to administer
>      them (although one format uses    IEEE
>      802 node identifiers, others do not). 
>      As a result, generation    on demand
>      can be completely automated, and used
>      for a variety of    purposes.  The
>      UUID generation algorithm described
>      here supports very    high allocation
>      rates of up to 10 million per second
>      per machine if    necessary, so that
>      they could even be used as transaction
>      IDs.
>
>    UUIDs are of a fixed size (128
>      bits) which is reasonably small
>      compared to other alternatives.  This
>      lends itself well to sorting,
>      ordering, and hashing of all sorts,
>      storing in databases, simple
>      allocation, and ease of programming in
>      general.